# R - treating first element of a list as a special case

Tags: r

I want to run a loop over a list, treating the first element as a special case. I tried:

```
# do stuff for element 1
for (i = 2:length(l)) {
     # do stuff
}
```

But this causes problems if the length is 1, because 2:1 = c(2,1). What's the best way to write that code?

In fact, I'd like to be able to loop through a list like

```
for (i = 1:length(l)) {
     # do stuff
}
```

without creating problems if the list is empty. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: `head` is the way to go, but you could also use `a[seq_len(n)]`.

Comment: Have you considered using `lapply`?

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use `setdiff`:

```
# do stuff for element 1

for(i in setdiff(seq_along(l), 1)) {
   # do stuff
}
```

or using `tail`

```
# do stuff for element 1

for(i in tail(seq_along(l), -1)) {
   # do stuff
}
```

or simply use:

```
# do stuff for element 1

for(i in (seq_along(l))[-1]) {
   # do stuff
}
```

***Edit for updated question:*** You can safely access the indices by doing

```
for(i in seq_along(l)) {
  # do stuff
}
```

or directly access each element in the list by

```
for(elem in l) {
  # do stuff
}
```

Comment: Fixed your code as it was failing in the case when `length(l) == 0`. Never use `:` in these situations or it will bite you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `for` directly in the list.

```
for (i in l[-1]) { ... }
```